# Force Kodi to fill cachemembuffer

Tags: kodi

I am trying to avoid waiting for caching during playback. Waiting before starting playback is acceptable.

We can assume the server is slow, so the goal is to make Kodi cache several minutes of video no matter how long this takes.

Using the add-on Easy Advanced Settings I have changed:

```
<advancedsettings>
 <network>
  <buffermode>1</buffermode>
  <readbufferfactor>20</readbufferfactor> (I have also tried 2 here)
  <cachemembuffersize> 312345678 </cachemembuffersize>
 </network>
</advancedsettings>
```

So if the video rate is 10 Mbit/s I want the system to cache 4 minutes of video.

The above only caches less than 30 seconds.

How can I tell Kodi to read-ahead and fill the complete cachemembuffer?

Kodi version: 17 Android

Answer (score 0):

The tags are renamed in version 17:

https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Modify_the_video_cache